# Interpreting EPSG:4326 coordinates in a .tif file for a DEM

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio, epsg

I am working on a piece of algorithm where I need to have access to ground altitude values from a digital elevation model. The model that I am using is SRTM1, which I access to by using the elevation package in Python, as like:

```
    import rasterio as rio
    import elevation

    dem_bounds = tuple(configs["dem_aware_monoplotting"]["dem_bounds"])
    output_file = "dem_fields.tif"
    elevation.clip(bounds=dem_bounds, product='SRTM1', output=output_file)
    dem = rio.open(output_file)
```

The elevation data is in the coordinate system EPSG:4326. The Rasterio DatasetReader object `dem` has a property that contains the affine transformation matrix that maps the image data to the actual CRS coordinates, which is in this case:

```
Affine(0.0002777777777777778, 0.0, 12.34986111111111,
       0.0, -0.0002777777777777778, 42.00013888888889)
```

The first entry in the first row and the second one in the second row shows the pixel width and height in the original image, in the CRS units, degrees.

I am confused by the following fact: EPSG:4326 is a geographic system, it is not projected and it is following latitude, longitude values. The longitude values should correspond to different lengths in meters, as one gets more distant from the equator line. In the SRTM website, it is being said that the spatial resolution is around 30 meters in this elevation model. However, how can this be valid since 1 degree of longitude is corresponding to different actual lengths on the ellipsoid based on the latitude value?

For example, a DEM crop from somewhere near the equator can have have 30 meters of resolution in pixel widths, but would it be still be 30 meters again when we go near to the poles?

I am actually not from a GIS background, so this could be a very trivial issue for a domain expert, however I think I am lost in the concepts here.

Comment: It's more accurate to say, "At most, 30 meters," which deals with the compression along lines of latitude toward the poles. By the time a DTED product nears the poles, the pixel width, in degrees, has doubled twice. And the shuttle couldn't get the high in amplitude.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This means that, when we near the poles, the pixel width is actually covering a lower resolution, like 50 meters of distance, so there is a warping effect, is that correct?

Comment: The SRTM dataset extends only to 60° north and 56° south, so it is not reaching the extreme latitudes.

Comment: No, the opposite; at the Equator a degree is 60 nautical miles; at the poles it's zero. So "at most" means that the pixel is a little wider than tall at the Equator, and way smaller as you get to higher latitudes (cosine)